# setting sequence value as default for column in HSQL

Tags: hsqldb, alter-table

I have a query that looks like this in postgres:

```
ALTER TABLE alias_table ALTER COLUMN iddb SET DEFAULT nextval('alias_table_iddb_seq');
```

I would like to translate it into `hsql`. I know that I can do it by enabling PostgreSQL syntax Compatibility:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE;
ALTER TABLE alias_table ALTER COLUMN iddb SET DEFAULT nextval('alias_table_iddb_seq');
```

However I'm interested in pure hsql syntax. I know I could do it on create table syntax using something like:

```
CREATE TABLE alias_table ( 
  iddb bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE alias_table_iddb_seq PRIMARY KEY
);
```

But, how can I do it from `alter table` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only supported ALTER TABLE syntax is in the PGS compatibility mode.

In the next version (2.5.1) syntax similar to that used for CREATE TABLE will be supported.

```
ALTER TABLE alias_table ALTER COLUMN iddb GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE alias_table_iddb_seq
```

Comment: thanks, do you know when it's planned to be released?

Comment: Not yet --------